# Setting data in a multi dimensional array

Tags: magento-1, magento2-dev-beta

All classes that extend `Varien_Object` in Magento 1 and `Magento\Framework\Object` in Magento 2 have a method called `getData`. All of us used it.
If the `$_data` member var is a multidimensional array we can access the data from any level through a single call of `getData`.
Example:

```
$_data = array(
    'a' => array(
        'a1' => array(
            a11' => 'valA'
        ),
        'a2' => 'valA2'
     ),
     'b' => 'valB'
)
```

so calling `$obj->getData('a')` will return

```
array(
    'a1' => array(
        a11' => 'valA'
    ),
    'a2' => 'valA2'
);
```

calling `$obj->getData('a/a1')` will return

```
array(
    a11' => 'valA'
)
```

calling `$obj->getData('a/a1/a11')` will return `valA`.
You get the point.

Is there a similar way of setting data for a specific path or do I have to do it myself?

I mean  `$obj->setData('a/a1/a11', 'something')` results in

```
$_data['a/a1/a11'] = 'something'
```

I need something that will translate into

```
$_data['a']['a1']['a11'] = 'something';
```

It can be something from Magento 1 or Magento 2. It's not really important.
I will accept also an answer like "this is not possible out of the box" but from a trusted source only. (read "core dev").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did't find sucha method in the core code for M1 or M2.
But I found something close to what I need [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2447408/2047249).
My adaptation of the script looks like this:

```
/**
 * set data by path
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @param mixed $value
 * @return $this
 */
public function setDataByPath($path, $value)
{
    $data = &$this->_data;

    if (!is_array($path)) {
        $path = explode('/', $path);
    }
    $key = array_pop($path);
    foreach ($path as $k) {
        if (!isset($data[$k])) {
            $data[$k] = array();
        }
        $data = &$data[$k];
    }
    $data[$key ? $key : count($data)] = $value;
    return $this;
}
```

After doing some tests this seams to work. If someone thinks this is wrong , just let me know.
I can use the method above like this:

```
 $obj->setDataByPath('a/a1/a11', 'something');
```

this is the same thing as

```
 $_data['a']['a1']['a11'] = 'something';
```

and

```
 $obj->setDataByPath('a/a1', 'something_else');
```

is the same as

```
 $_data['a']['a1'] = 'something_else';
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you specifically want something using a path type key, if not can't you just do the following:

```
$data = $obj->getData();
$data['a']['a1']['a11'] = 'something';
$obj->setData($data);
```

As setData overwrites all the the data in the object if $key is an array?

```
/**
 * Overwrite data in the object.
 *
 * $key can be string or array.
 * If $key is string, the attribute value will be overwritten by $value
 *
 * If $key is an array, it will overwrite all the data in the object.
 *
 * @param string|array $key
 * @param mixed $value
 * @return Varien_Object
 */
public function setData($key, $value=null)
```

Comment: Th reason I'm looking for what I asked is because I have to do a lot of operations like the one I described and I need a reusable piece of code. And the path I'm trying to set is not always going to be the same and it will not have the same length. Sometimes it will be `['a']['a1']['a11']` other times it will be `['a']['a1']` and other times it will be `['b']`. Thanks for taking your time to answer tough.